# PHP Array to JSON formatted object

Tags: php, json

I think I need another pair of eyes to review this code. I cant quite get the right combination of array statements to get the JSON object I want.

```
    $sql = "SELECT categories.category_name AS category_id, sub_categories.sub_category_name AS subcategory_id, items.id AS item_id, items.item_name
            FROM categories
            LEFT JOIN sub_categories ON (categories.id = sub_categories.category_id)
            LEFT JOIN items ON (sub_categories.id = items.sub_category_id)
            WHERE categories.site_id = 1
            ORDER BY category_id,subcategory_id";


    $result1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $sql) or trigger_error("Query: $sql\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    if($result1 === FALSE)
    {
        echo(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    } else
    {



    $tempCategoryArray = array();
    $tempSubCategoryArray = array();

    $categoriesArray = array("categories" => array());
    $category = "";
    $sub_category = "";
    $newCat= FALSE;
    $newSubCat = FALSE;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 


        {

        // If we have a new category, let's start anew

        if($row['category_id'] != $category) 
                {

                $tempCategoryArray['category_id'][]= $row['category_id'];

                // Add the temporary array to the main one
                    if(!empty($tempCategoryArray)) 
                        {
                       array_push ($categoriesArray['categories'], $tempCategoryArray);

                        }


                    $tempCategoryArray = array();


                    $tempCategoryArray['subcategories'] = array();

                }


                $category = $row['category_id'];
        // Same here, if a new sub, let's start fresh

        if($row['subcategory_id'] != $sub_category) 
                {

                $tempSubCategoryArray['subcategory_id'][] = $row['subcategory_id'];
                $tempSubCategoryArray['items'] = array(); 
                        // Add it to the tempCategory
                    if(!empty($tempSubCategoryArray)) 
                        {
                        array_push   ($tempCategoryArray['subcategories'], $tempSubCategoryArray);


                        }




                }

                 { 
                   $tempSubCategoryArray['items'] = array(); 


                      array_push($tempSubCategoryArray['items'],array('item_name'=>     $row['item_name'], 'item_id'=> $row['item_id'], 'item_qty'=> 0));
                       array_push($tempCategoryArray,$tempSubCategoryArray['items']);



                      unset($tempSubCategoryArray);

                 }

        // Finally, no need for temporary arrays with items, since they have no sub-    array

                $sub_category= $row['subcategory_id'];


        }
    array_push ($categoriesArray['categories'], $tempCategoryArray);
    }

    //var_dump($categoriesArray);
    $categoryJson = json_encode($categoriesArray);

    echo $categoryJson;

    //echo '<script  src="js/menupages.js"></script>';


    // Clean up:
    mysqli_free_result($result1);

    ?>
```

This is the object I am getting and variations of it when I make changes but I just cant get it to my targeted JSON object

Current JSON

```
{
"categories":[
  {
     "category_id":[
        "Drinks"
     ]
  },
  {
     "subcategories":[
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Beer"
           ],
           "items":[

           ]
        },
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Wine"
           ],
           "items":[

           ]
        }
     ],
     "0":[
        {
           "item_name":"Miller   Lite",
           "item_id":"5",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "1":[
        {
           "item_name":"Yuengling",
           "item_id":"6",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "2":[
        {
           "item_name":"Bud Select",
           "item_id":"7",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "3":[
        {
           "item_name":"White Zin",
           "item_id":"8",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "4":[
        {
           "item_name":"Reistling",
           "item_id":"10",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "category_id":[
        "Food"
     ]
  },
  {
     "subcategories":[
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Sandwiches"
           ],
           "items":[

           ]
        }
     ],
     "0":[
        {
           "item_name":"Hamburger",
           "item_id":"9",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ],
     "1":[
        {
           "item_name":"Hot Dog",
           "item_id":"11",
           "item_qty":0
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

The JSON I really want

```
{
"categories":[
  {
     "category_id":[
        "Drinks"
     ]
  },
  {
     "subcategories":[
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Beer"
           ],
           "items":[
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Miller Lite",
                    "item_id":"5",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ],
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Yuengling",
                    "item_id":"6",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ],
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Bud Select",
                    "item_id":"7",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ]
           ]
        },
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Wine"
           ],
           "items":[
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"White Zin",
                    "item_id":"8",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ],
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Reistling",
                    "item_id":"10",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ]
           ]
        }
     ],
     "category_id":[
        "Food"
     ]
  },
  {
     "subcategories":[
        {
           "subcategory_id":[
              "Sandwiches"
           ],
           "items":[
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Hamburger",
                    "item_id":"9",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ],
              [
                 {
                    "item_name":"Hot Dog",
                    "item_id":"11",
                    "item_qty":0
                 }
              ]
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: I think even your desired format is an odd format.  Why would you have your category object and the subcategory object related to it in the same level of the structure? Should the subcategory arrays not be a property of the category objects?

Comment: I agree that your desired structure is odd. I'd personally go with something much simpler like http://pastie.org/private/yyfrxuuo7qvr1i72wvpjq .  Also, you seem to have some PHP missing. At one point your code goes right from a close curly brace into an open curly brace (`}{`);

Comment: I do like that structure better. I will try that one and see if I can make that work easier. And yes the }{ was an Else statement i removed earlier